# How do I use ldapsearch with a cross-realm ticket?

Tags: ldap, kerberos, sasl, gssapi

`kinit user@DOMAIN.TLD`
`klist -afe`

> Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000
>   Default principal: user@DOMAIN.TLD
>   Valid starting     Expires            Service principal
>   08/04/11 13:14:53  08/05/11 01:14:53  krbtgt/DOMAIN.TLD@DOMAIN.TLD
>       renew until 08/05/11 13:14:53, Flags: FRI
>       Etype (skey, tkt): des3-cbc-sha1, des3-cbc-sha1
>       Addresses: (none)

`ldapwhoami -h dc1.windows.domain.tld`

> SASL/GSSAPI authentication started
>   ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Local error (-2)
>       additional info: SASL(-1): generic failure: GSSAPI Error: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information (Server ldap/dc1.windows.DOMAIN.TLD@DOMAIN.TLD not found in Kerberos database)

`kvno ldap/dc1.windows.domain.tld@WINDOWS.DOMAIN.TLD`
`ldap/dc1.windows.domain.tld@WINDOWS.DOMAIN.TLD: kvno = 65`

`klist -afe`

> Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000
>   Default principal: user@DOMAIN.TLD
>   Valid starting     Expires            Service principal
>   08/04/11 13:14:53  08/05/11 01:14:53  krbtgt/DOMAIN.TLD@DOMAIN.TLD
>       renew until 08/05/11 13:14:53, Flags: FRI
>       Etype (skey, tkt): des3-cbc-sha1, des3-cbc-sha1
>       Addresses: (none)
>   08/04/11 13:24:35  08/05/11 01:14:53  krbtgt/WINDOWS.DOMAIN.TLD@DOMAIN.TLD
>       renew until 08/05/11 13:14:53, Flags: FRT
>       Etype (skey, tkt): des-cbc-crc, des-cbc-crc
>       Addresses: (none)
>   08/04/11 13:24:35  08/05/11 01:14:53 ldap/dc1.windows.domain.tld@WINDOWS.DOMAIN.TLD 
>       renew until 08/05/11 13:14:53, Flags: FR
>       Etype (skey, tkt): arcfour-hmac, arcfour-hmac
>       Addresses: (none)

`ldapwhoami -h dc1.windows.domain.tld`

> SASL/GSSAPI authentication started
>   ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Local error (-2)
>       additional info: SASL(-1): generic failure: GSSAPI Error: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information (Server ldap/dc1.windows.domain.tld@DOMAIN.TLD not found in Kerberos database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insufficient domain realm mapping.

Required either
krb5.conf:
`[domain_realm]`
`windows.domain.tld = WINDOWS.DOMAIN.TLD`
`.windows.domain.tld = WINDOWS.DOMAIN.TLD`
or
DNS:
`_kerberos.windows.domain.tld. TXT "WINDOWS.DOMAIN.TLD"`

Only had
DNS:
`_kerberos.domain.tld.  IN TXT "DOMAIN.TLD"`

Answer (score 0):

the ldapserver needs to be the first entry in /etc/hosts

```
192.168.1.5  fqdn.of.your.ad.server some.other.name and.another
```

If everything is correctly in dns, then remove the line from /etc/hosts all together.